# How can I make hex link in python django?

Tags: python, django

In my models file I have class called Question and for link to the current Question I'm using `path('<int:pk>/', views.QuestionCurrent)`. And i want to make links to be hex not int. Can I do that and if I can, how?

Comment: So it is a hex number? Or a hex string?

Comment: my links are int and i wanted to be hex number (0-F system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [*custom path converter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) for that.

You can for example define such converter in a file `app/converters.py`:

```
# app/converters.py

class HexConverter:
    regex = '[0-9a-fA-F]+'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return int(value, 16)

    def to_url(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = int(value)
        return hex(value)[2:]
```

Next you can register the path converter, and then specify this:

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from app import converters, views

register_converter(converters.HexConverter, 'hex')

urlpatterns = [
    path('<hex:pk>/', views.QuestionCurrent, name='question_current'),
]
```

If you now visit `/1f/` for example, the primary key `pk` passed to the `QuestionCurrent`, will be 31. The same will happen if you use `question_current` in an `{% url … %}` template tag. If you write `{% url 'question_current' pk=31 %}`, it will be translated to `/1f/`.